# CheckBox sound stopping

Tags: java, swing, audio, checkbox, javasound

Music works just fine when i click on the box, but music won't stop when I click on it again. Then if i click on the unchecked box again, the music plays again so 2 times at once! Please help me with stopping the music!

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("panda - desiigner (donald trump remix).au");
    AudioStream audioStream = null;

try {
    audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(kekFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
int check;
if(jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true){
    check = 1;
} else {
    check = 0;
}
switch (check) {
    case 1 : AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream); 
             System.out.println("Music has started playing");
             break;
    case 0 : AudioPlayer.player.stop(audioStream); 
             System.out.println("Music has stopped playing");
             break;
}



}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
```

Comment: Please share code of AudioPlayer too

Comment: where, how can i do that?

Comment: @DarkKnight The `import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;` is an undocumented (& 'no source available') class internal to the (Oracle) JRE. OP: Don't use those classes. Use a [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) from the `javax.sound.sampled` package instead.

Comment: `Then if i click on the unchecked box again, the music plays again so 2 times at once!` Well every time you click on the check box you create a `new AudioStream(...)` I suspect you should only create one. Then you use methods of the AudioStream to start/stop the music. Read the API.

Comment: @MatějPospíšil Let me know whether my solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have properly created a Clip, and can access both it and a boolean (isSelected, say) that reflects the state of the JCheckBox, the following simple code should work:

```
    if (isSelected)
    {
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    }
    else
    {
        clip.stop();
    }
```

This can be included in the JCheckBox's ActionListener.

More information about using Clips can be found on the Java Tutorial's "Audio Thread" with specifics about the Clips [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html). There are clearer examples elsewhere if you do a search on how to use a Java Clip. The official Java Tutorial for audio emphasizes background and high-level concepts at the expense of practical examples, imho, which makes for difficult reading for those of us who are just starting out.

sun.audio.AudioPlayer is no longer supported! Even if it works on your PC, there is no guarantee it will work on other systems. Unfortunately, this is a situation where obsolete code examples live on in blogs and unofficial tutorials, which can happen a lot as languages evolve and the parties that wrote the tutorials don't update or maintain their posts.

---

In response to the OP's request, here is an example adapted from one of my JavaFX gui's. I don't use Swing anymore and am not keen to go back.

In the code where the JavFX [Button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) is being built:

```
    btnPlay = new Button("Play");
    btnPlay.setOnAction(e -> handlePlay(e));
```

This calls the following method:

```
private void handlePlay(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (!isPlaying)
    {
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
        ((Button)e.getSource()).setText("STOP");
        isPlaying = true;
    }
    else
    {
        clip.stop();
        ((Button)e.getSource()).setText("PLAY");
        isPlaying = false;
    }
}
```

In this code, *isPlaying* is an instance variable that in this case merely tells us whether the button is on or off. The clip may very well play to its end and stop on its own while the button is still in a "playing" state. It would require wiring up a LineListener to have the button toggle back when the clip finishes playing.

Maybe you can adapt the above into something useful? It seems to me the choice of JCheckBox is dubious, and a JToggleButton might be a better choice. Examples of writing Listeners for Swing Buttons can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: It would help alot.